# Using do while loops

Tags: loops

The loops still continue even though I type "0" for quantity. What is wrong here and how can I fix this to stop when I type "0" for quantity?

```
Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total ;
        int quantity = 0;
        String name = null;
        double price;

        
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please type the quantity of your item(s) (ex : If you have 2 shirts, please type 2)");
            quantity = myinput.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Please type the name of your item(s)");
            name = myinput.next();

            System.out.println("Please type the price of your item(s)");
            price = myinput.nextDouble();
        
        }while (quantity == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quantity is 0. Your While-Loop asks "Is this Value 0? If it is, i will do this again." Which is exactly what happens.

In that case you simply have to change `while (quantity == 0)` to `while (quantity != 0)`, which basically asks the opposite.

"Is this Value not 0? If *it is* not 0, then i do this again. If it *is* 0, then i will stop doing this."

Comment: I want loop to stop when I type 0. Also, I changed "int quantity = 0" to "int quantity" but still doesn't work.. Loop doesn't stop even though I type 0 for quantity. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Again. Change the expression in the while loop to "quantity != 0".

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70574950/12675597), you need to change the 'do while' condition. You can either check for `quantity != 0` or `quantity > 0`. Hence you will have

```
do
{

//your code here

}while (quantity > 0)
```

This way it only enters the loop once, the first time, when it will ask for quantity, name and price, and THEN it will check if the quantity is different/bigger than 0. If you want to check the quantity before name and price, you should do separate do while loops for each check.